# Vue.js Router: why $route.router.go() not working?

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vue.js, vue-router

Why doesn't work redirect to page with [vue-router](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/tree/1.0) 0.7.13 + [SweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/)? I do like this (Laravel 5.3):

Here is `article.blade.php`:

```
...
<a href="#" v-on:click.prevent="deleteArticle('/articles/{{ $article->id }}/delete')">Delete</a>
...
```

This is my `app.js`:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
window.VueRouter = require('vue-router');
Vue.use(VueRouter);

var article_form = new Vue({
  el: '#article_form',
  data: {
    ...
  },
  methods: {
    ...
    ...
    deleteArticle: function (url) { // Click Delete button
      var self = this;
      swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
        closeOnConfirm: false
      }, function () { // Click Yes button
        self.$http.delete(url).then(function () {
          swal({
            title: "Deleted!",
            text: "Your imaginary file has been deleted.",
            type: "success"
          }, function () { // After click ОК must be redirect
            self.$route.router.go('/articles');
          });
        });
      });
    }
  }
});
```

And `package.json`:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-14",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.9",
    "vue-resource": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "sweetalert": "^1.1.3",
    "vue": "^1.0.28",
    "vue-router": "^0.7.13"
  }
}
```

There is an error (from OS X Safari console): `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'self.$route.router')`.

I tried more like this: `self.$router.go('/articles')`, but it show me same error. Somehow for him `$route` (or `$router`) as an `undefined`.

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to actually install the plugin:

```
var VueRouter = require ('vue-router')
Vue.use (VueRouter)
```

Comment: @VikkyShostak This may not solve the problem but worth noticing: `go` is used like `go(1)` or `go(-1)` to jump forward/backward, use `this.$router.push('/articles')` in your case. I tested and `go('/articles')` somehow reloads the page.

Comment: @PanJunjie潘俊杰 `push` method work on vue-router 0.7.13?

Comment: @VikkyShostak sorry, didn't notice the version info, I'm using vue-router 2.x and talked based on it, may not be right.

Comment: @PanJunjie潘俊杰 I'm switch `vue` and `vue-router` to 2.x version, but steel look this error on console. Why?

Comment: @VikkyShostak Use `this.$router` in your case, it's used for navigation, while `$route` is for getting route info like `this.$route.path`. But you probably have already tried `this.$router.push`, and vue-router is properly installed, it looks all fine...